# How can I configure apache to cache the images that it is serving? Right now it is giving headers that look like: "max-age=0"

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

### Serving up images that don't seem to cache

There's a LAPP stack (postgresql instead of mysql) running over on http://ninjawars.net.  I just recently noticed that images don't seem to be caching with any kind of good frequency as I was reloading a page with a few images on it here:
http://www.ninjawars.net/attack_player.php

Here is an example image (they're probably all being served exactly the same):
http://www.ninjawars.net/images/characters/fighter.png
Checking the header, it seems that the caching is set to: `Cache-Control:max-age=0`

(the full header for this image, like all the others, is...

> Request
>   URL:http://www.ninjawars.net/images/characters/fighter.png
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK
>   Request Headers
>   Accept:application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
>   Cache-Control:max-age=0
>   Referer:http://www.ninjawars.net/images/characters/fighter.png
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux
>   x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.3
>   Safari/533.4 Response Headers
>   Accept-Ranges:bytes Content-Length:938
>   Content-Type:image/png Date:Thu, 13
>   May 2010 21:24:07 GMT
>   ETag:"ffd4d-3aa-4837efc120540"
>   Last-Modified:Mon, 05 Apr 2010
>   15:28:45 GMT Server:Apache

)

**So what modules or config or htaccess or whatever do I change to have it cache images, e.g. for 24 hours?**

Answer (score 1):

[mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html)

But what you really want to do is move them off to a CDN.

Comment: Err, you mean like a third-party CDN?  Do you have one that you recommend that I could use or something?

Comment: I mean, I'm vaguely aware of amazon's s3 stuff, but I wasn't really aware of any other major push to act as a CDN for arbitrary person.

Comment: I haven't used them myself but SimpleCDN looks like a fit.